# What are the "Files" that Metatag module allows adding Metadata to?

Tags: 7, meta-tags

In Drupal 7, if you go to `Configuration > Search and metadata > Metatag > Settings (Tab)` the module [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) allows you to add Metatags to "Files"... What are these files?... As everyone are knows, files are not webpages and I guess there aren't very much good reasons to build themselves as web pages... So why would the module attach them \ associate them with meta tags???[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all the files managed by Drupal through attachments, images & file fields. In D7, these managed files are entities. As such, the metatag module supports it.

This isn't useful with the metatag module alone, but if you had a configuration where files had their own display page (e.g. the [file entity & media module](https://www.drupal.org/node/1793548)), it could be utilized.

Comment: I think I need to have some more detailing to understand you better - I don't understand for example, generally, is it wise to give certain files meta tags? Why is it good for if they won't act as "Web-pages"? I've never done that and got not once and not twice satisfying SEO results... Please, for all readers to come, and for my better understanding, add such data to your answer... Thanks!

Comment: I revised the explaining the utility of using metatag with files.